# New command for Covariance not working

Tags: macros, statistics

I am trying to use `\newcommand` for `\mathrm{Cov}` but in my output I am not getting the symbol for Covariance as I wanted.

My LaTeX code:

```
$\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$
\begin{align*}
   A\Cov(X_1,Y)_{i,j} + B\Cov(X_2,Y)_{i,j} = 
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please, make a complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. But if this is specific for MathJax or similar, you should state it explicitly (and it would be mostly off-topic). Anyway, `\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}` works also in MathJax.

Comment: Your command is inside a math group, so its definition is lost when the math group ends. Put it outside the `$...$`

Comment: As egreg mentions your should use DeclareMathOpetator, in the preamble. Using just mathrm like this gives you the wrong spacing on Cov. We might as well build the spacing into the macro now that we can. Var and friends are defined similarly